KCL and KVL usage and relationship between the currents
Improved 1st image (for readability)

Improved 2nd image (for readability)

Translation of the question: "What relationship exists between the currents {iLa, i_b, iLc}?"
So was trying to solve the above question. I could understand that have to use the Krichhoff's loop law. And the second picture shows my probe. But I'm stuck at some point in bringing out the relationship between the currents {iLa, i_b, iLc}. Please give your insights on solving this questions. Lemme know where I'm going wrong and how should think about the solution. Correct me.

After amending your post by improving the images it strikes me that you are giving electric field and voltages the same name and this is confusing. I don't see that there is any need to show electric fields at all. Also, I cannot see current iLa nor iLc so, I believe you need to significantly improve this post.

Sorry for the confusion. The directions that I used indicates the directions of the potential drop.

But you have arrows pointing one way and arrows pointing the other way --> Vo for instance

Yah got the mistake. Thanks for bringing it to the attention.

For this problem it's helpful to know an alternative form of KCL called (in English) the cut set form of KCL.
This says that if you draw a line through your circuit, the sum of all the current passing through the line in a chosen direction is zero.
Of course this works only if all the wires of the circuit are drawn rather than represented by labels or ground symbols or off-sheet connectors or whatever. You must also have any sources, such as inputs and power supplies drawn in rather than only indicated by labels.
In your circuit you can draw a horizontal line through just where the arrows for the specified currents are drawn, and the arrows all point from top to bottom.

Therefore the sum of those currents must be zero.

Interesing. Will learn it to perfection. Thank you.

The task is difficult if the circuit is kept as it is. But by rotating and carefully observing the circuit you find that it is a Wheatstone bridge with a resistance in parallel and a transverse one. In the following there is a topological analysis of the network and the determination of the required relationships:







